# How to Bind Sum of width of two control to MinWidth of another control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, casting, multibinding

I wanna set MinWidth of column of grid, which should be sum of Actual Width of a Label and a Button control inside another grid placed inside the cell of a column. I am using a Converter class for this purpose but figure out the XAML part.
Converter is here:

```
class StringSumtoIntConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            sum += System.Convert.ToInt32(item);
        }

        return sum;
    }
    //...Other implementations
}
```

XAML code I have written till now is:

```
xmlns:helperClasses="clr-namespace:EmbroidaryManagementSystem_V2._0.HelperClasses" <!--Import class-->

<helperClasses:StringSumtoIntConverter x:Key="StringSumtoIntConvert"/>  <!--Inside Window.Resources tag-->

<ColumnDefinition Width="48*"> <!--Inside Grid-->
    <ColumnDefinition.MinWidth>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringSumtoIntConvert}">
            <Binding Path=""></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ColumnDefinition.MinWidth>
</ColumnDefinition>
```

Complete implementation of XAML is here:

```
<Window x:Class="EmbroidaryManagementSystem_V2._0.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmbroidaryManagementSystem_V2._0.View"
    xmlns:y="clr-namespace:EmbroidaryManagementSystem_V2._0.ViewModel.CollectionsViewModel"
    xmlns:helperClasses="clr-namespace:EmbroidaryManagementSystem_V2._0.HelperClasses"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="655.512" Width="1120.159" FontSize="24" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    >
<Window.Resources>
    <helperClasses:StringSumtoIntConverter x:Key="StringSumtoIntConvert"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <y:ClientCollectionVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="622" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1110" Background="#FFD6DBE9">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="89*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="39*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="494*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="137*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="48*">
            <ColumnDefinition.MinWidth>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringSumtoIntConvert}">
                    <Binding Path=""></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ColumnDefinition.MinWidth>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitter" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="533" Grid.Row="1" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Height="35" Background="#FF657695" 
          Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Label x:Name="lblNotificationsHeader" Content="Notifications" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14.667" Height="30" Foreground="#FFEBF0EE"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnNotificationsClose" Content="X" 
                Margin="0,5,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" FontFamily="Verdana" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" FontSize="13.333" Foreground="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Also there is an error saying: Unable to cast object of type 'EmbroidaryManagementSystem_V2._0.ViewModel.CollectionsViewModel.ClientCollectionVM' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
At line:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringSumtoIntConvert}">
                        <Binding Path=""></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
```

I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the values to the converter in the MultiBinding.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringSumtoIntConvert}">
    <Binding ElementName="lblNotificationsHeader" Path="ActualWidth" />
    <Binding ElementName="btnNotificationsClose" Path="ActualWidth" />
</MultiBinding>
```

The error is because Path is empty, which means it's picking up the DataContext and attempting to pass it to the converter which is unable to cast ClientCollectionVM to an int.

I'm not 100% sure where you are going with all of this, but you could probably nix the converter and just do:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The column would then expand to fit it's contents. Of course then you would want to change the inner Grid to a StackPanel with Horizontal orientation:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Height="35"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Background="#FF657695"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="lblNotificationsHeader"
               Height="30"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Content="Notifications"
               FontSize="14.667"
               Foreground="#FFEBF0EE" />
        <Button x:Name="btnNotificationsClose"
                Margin="0,5,8,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Background="Transparent"
                Content="X"
                FontFamily="Verdana"
                FontSize="13.333"
                Foreground="Black" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Either that or give the inner Grid it's own column definitions to separate the Label and Button out.

**Update**

Based on your update to add the GridSplitter, I've included a full example of how to achieve what you are after.

Keep in mind that, in your example, the GridSplitter is really resizing the left column no matter which direction you drag it, and the right column is just expanding to fill. So our goal is not to have a `MinWidth` on your right column, but instead a `MaxWidth` on our left column.

One quick change to your converter, since `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are doubles, let's change the converter to use doubles instead of integers so that we do not end up with stray pixels.

```
public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            sum += System.Convert.ToDouble(item);
        }

        return sum;
    }
```

We're going to put the GridSplitter in it's own column, set that columns width to `"2"` set the first ColumnDefinition's width to `"4*"` and the third to `"*"`. The `"4*"` is really just a random number, star sizing works off of percentages, so 4 won't always work, it just did in this case.

We also need to add some columns to the inner grid, we'll give those a name and use those elements to get the widths for our MultiBinding. We do that instead of getting the widths from the elements themselves, because ActualWidth does not include margins.

```
<Grid Background="#FFD6DBE9">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="89*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="494*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            <ColumnDefinition.MinWidth>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringSumtoIntConvert}">
                    <Binding ElementName="cdNotificationHeaderLabel" Path="ActualWidth" />
                    <Binding ElementName="cdNotificationHeaderButton" Path="ActualWidth" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ColumnDefinition.MinWidth>
        </ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter x:Name="gridSplitter"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Width="2"
                  ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="2"
          Height="35"
          Background="#FF657695">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="cdNotificationHeaderLabel" Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="cdNotificationHeaderButton" Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="lblNotificationsHeader"
               Margin="0 0 5 0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Content="Notifications"
               FontSize="14.667"
               Foreground="#FFEBF0EE" />
        <Button x:Name="btnNotificationsClose"
                Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="Transparent"
                Content="X"
                FontFamily="Verdana"
                FontSize="13.333"
                Foreground="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

All that said, I'd recommend deriving a custom control from GridSplitter and handling it that way, but the above should help to get you up and running.

Comment: It worked, but now there is another problem arose. Actually there is a splitter between columns (I've re-added its code that was previously removed in an edit by mistake). And the problem is when I change the size to the right and Notifications label goes out of the boundary of Grid, its ActualWidth decreases (so far I've noticed using debugger) and Converter is called repetitively with decreased width each time. I want this ActualWidth to be fixed as the very initial value.

Comment: making width of first and second column to "*" and "Auto" didn't help. I also tried to set MinWidth of inner Grid, and it also didn't help. I have placed the Label and the Button in same column and row just because of no apparent need to seperate them.

Comment: Well, the main concept I was missing was Horizontal and Vertical Alignments of the GridSplitter. I have placed the GridSplitter in its own like you suggested and then made its both alignments "Center". This way I was able to control the size of both first and third columns, afterall I had to to maintain the MinWidth of TabControl in first column as well. So Thanks a ton for your help. I was avoiding any code thing in this view because I am new to WPF and I just wanted to experiment things in XAML particularly.

Comment: One other thing that I did different than your code was, (I wanted near to "zero" space between lblNotificationsHeader and btnNotificationsClose when it stops resizing, ActualWidths of columns of inner grid were not doing it right) I set MinWidth of first column of inner grid to the Width of lblNotificationsHeader and the Width of second column to Auto, and then set the bindings to be MinWidth of cdNotificationHeaderLabel and ActualWidth of cdNotificationHeaderButton. This way it worked like a charm. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad you got it working and that's what I love about WPF, there is usually a multitude of ways to do something.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying anything in the binding, so its passing in your data context which is the VM. The VM isn't convertible to an int. You need to pass in {Binding ElementName=btnNotificationsClose, Path=ActualWidth} and the same for lblNotificationsHeader.

Honestly, though, it sounds like you are over complicating things. Grid row/columns aren't resizable unless you use a splitter which you aren't.

Comment: Actually I am using splitter, I just removed it in the edit, just with the thought to provide simplicity. sorry for any inconvinience.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Richard Preziosi also answered the same.

Comment: now there is another problem arose. Actually there is a splitter between columns (I've re-added its code that was previously removed in an edit by mistake). And the problem is when I change the size to the right and Notifications label goes out of the boundary of Grid, its ActualWidth decreases (so far I've noticed using debugger) and Converter is called repetitively with decreased width each time. I want this ActualWidth to be fixed as the very initial value.

Comment: @user3357779, yes, that's a known issue with the GridSplitter. You need to create a derived class and catch the mouse dragging to prevent it from going too far to the right.

Comment: Richard Preziosi's work around in his update worked without having to derive class and working with events in code. Anyhow thanks for your help.